# Render link in Grid cell with custom "click" handler

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs, grid

I am rendering a custom link in ExtJS Grid via my own renderrer:

```
function renderLink( val ) {
    return '<a href="javascript:void(0);">' + val + '</a>';
}
```

What is the easiest way to attach a "click" event listener to it?

Of course after all rows in grid are rendered I could iterate through every record from the grid store and on each of it:

```
Ext.get('....').on('click', ....);
```

But for me it sounds rather workaround than real solution... Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function renderLink( val ){
   return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="someMethod(); return false;">' + val + '</a>';
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that handler method is a internal method of an object, in which I take care of the grid, so I can't access it globally from `onclick="..."`, that is why I need to attach it via ExtJS `Element.on` method...

Comment: would it not be possible to create the object which contains the method and then call the method on that object?Or else create a global function which will expose this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach click event for example with dblclick listener:

```
listeners: {
        dblclick : {
            fn: function() { 
                var selectedRecord  = Ext.getCmp('ObjectsGrid').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                console.log(selectedRecord);


            },
            element: 'body'
        }
    }
```

All columns values can be seen by *console.log(selectedRecord):*